# elements overlayed over another in a grid is not getting inputs in xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, grid-layout

Adding elements in a grid shows all the elements one over the other but the lastly added element is not getting the inputs(taps)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid>
          <-- some elements -->
     </Grid>
      <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                VerticalOptions="Center">
               <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding command1}" />
                 </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                 <Label Text="" />
                                            
                 <Label Text="" />
        </StackLayout>
 </Grid>
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the `Accessibility`? Could you provide more details about what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [InputTransparent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.inputtransparent?view=xamarin-forms) property, set `InputTransparent="True"` on element that you want them to pass the tap event to elements located behind them.

> false if the element and its children should receive input; true if neither the element nor its children should receive input and should, instead, pass inputs to the elements that are visually behind the current visual element. Default is false.

Comment: My mistake.. the issue is once we turn on Talk back in accessibility...